# I Installed Addons Wrong and I Can't Fix It

Tags: add-on

I made the mistake of unzipping all the addons I just bought (I'm new to this) and installed them manually. They didn't show up in the list of addons I can click the checkmark for. I tried deleting the files and putting the zip folders inside the correct blender folder but when I try to install it correctly, it tells me it's already installed. I restarted blender many times and even restarted my computer hoping it would work, but it didn't. I'm at a complete loss as to what to do

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to follow what exactly did you do.

From where did you delete the "files"?

What zips you put into which folder?

I don't have many add-ons except the ones I've created myself (and then installed from Preferences / Add-ons > Install) but AFAIK Blender usually stores the installed add-ons in system user folder.

For example, for Windows 11 the path could be something like this (my computer and for 4.0 Blender):

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons

Better check that folder and see if you already have something there.

**Edit (based on discussion in comments)**

Consider downloading Blender again, remove existing install and reinstall Blender, if you have accidentally copied/unzipped files into you Blender install folder or its subfolders.

Then install the add-ons from add-ons panel.

If you haven't messed up anything in users folder (where Blender stores some editor settings), then the new Blender install will use those user folder settings.

Comment: I get this error: Source file is in the add-on search path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 4.0\\4.0\\scripts\\addons'

Comment: Did you unzip some files in Blender's install directory?

Comment: Yeah? Maybe? This all confuses me tbh

Comment: Well you could download Blender again, remove existing install and reinstall Blender. Then install the add-ons from add-ons panel. If you haven't messed up anything in users folder, then the new Blender install will anyway use those user folder settings.

Comment: Reinstalling blender, cutting the offending zip files and pasting them into a separate folder in documents, and reinstalling them manually finally worked! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: OK nice to hear! I edited part of this comments section discussion into answer, consider marking my answer as the solution, if that is ok. Or write the exact steps you took as your own answer :)